# gensim - ConcatenatedDoc2Vec: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testfixtures

Tags: gensim

I have

```
pip install gensim
```

But when I tried to import ConcatenatedDoc2Vec, I get
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testfixtures**

```
from gensim.test.test_doc2vec import ConcatenatedDoc2Vec
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to first

```
pip install testfixtures
```

Comment: Note that the `ConcatenatedDoc2Vec` is just a hacky wrapper class for gluing 2 different `Doc2Vec` vector-sets together, to try to reproduce a result from the original 'Paragraph Vectors'. It's only used in some Gensim demos/testing - hence its extra requirement for another package – & isn't necessary or recommended for most other uses. (My experiments didn't show the same benefit of such a concatenated-double-docvec that the 'Paragraph Vector' authors claimed.)